# Screen overlay setting in Redmi Note 3

Tags: mobile-application

How do I access the Screen Overlay setting for apps in Redmi Note 3? The setting for the apps gets reset to default and each time I have to again change the settings. Is there any solution to the above problem. There is no screen overlay setting in settings of Redmi note 3. Is there a way to access it?